# Flutterfire configure not working in any possible way

Tags: android, windows, flutter, firebase

I've tried to follow step by step all documentations, and I've miserably failed.
I'm creating my very first app with Flutter and Android Studio on **Windows**.

Error:

```
i Found 0 Firebase projects. Selecting project five-six-seven-and-eight.
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be 
installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

I've downloaded:

- the *standalone bin* in the project folder,
- I've renamed it in firebase.exe
- running *firebase login:ci*, saved the Token in System variables
- running firebase init
  login works, firebase projects:list works (I can see my project on firebase).

`Flutterfire configure`--> fails!

I've then tried via node.js.

- I've downloaded and installed Node.js
- via CMD I've run *npm install -g firebase-tools*
  I can see the login and project list, but `Flutterfire configure` still fails:

Fetching available Firebase projects...
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
#
^

- #0 _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
- #1 _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1250:9)
- #2 _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:915:22)
- #3 _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:35:10)
- #4 JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
- #5 runFirebaseCommand (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:95:25)
- #6 getProjects (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase.dart:114:7)
- #7 ConfigCommand._selectFirebaseProject (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:264:24)
- #8 ConfigCommand.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/config.dart:351:37)
- #9 CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
- #10 main (file:///C:/Users/***/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutterfire_cli-0.2.2+2/bin/flutterfire.dart:57:5)

I've tried logout and login again.
So then, I have no idea how to let my Flutter app in Android studio see/link/match my Firebase project so I can try my first auth.

Comment: This is still not fixed. What a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation a day ago.

After a lot of headaches, `npm install -g firebase-tools` works for me. Windows binary version has some bugs, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried all the solutions mentioned above.
and this the only one worked for me,

1. install node.js
2. add C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin to your system environment
3. go to your flutter project directory and run cmd
4. run this command. `npm install -g firebase-tools`
5. run the command of flutterfire configure

Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

To login with firebase run
npm: Run npm install -g firebase-tools

Add FlutterFire to Windows Environment Variables

C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgdcf.png)

Comment: Done. Nothing changed. I've this now and the FIREBASE_TOKEN as System environment variables.
If I run "flutterfire configure" via the standalone --> see error on top "i Found 0 Firebase projects...."
If I run the command via cmd --> "Fetching available Firebase projects... Unhandled exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) # ^..."

Comment: In case (like me) it doesn't work neither with cmd/npm neither with the standalone Firebase exe file. I've found this procedure that works:
1. Go one level up your project folder (e.g. C:\Users\d**\AndroidStudioProjects
2. Make sure you're login (firebase login:ci) and everything is well updated
3. Deactivate and reactivate the flutterfire_cli (RUN: dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli, then RUN: dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli)
4. RUN: cd dir 'nameofyourprojectfolder'
5 RUN: flutterfire configure in there

Comment: Dex, i tried and still have error "COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Running `flutterfire configure --verbose` after trying so many solutions worked for me, I am not sure why but it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I installed nodejs with nvm and then deleted firebase.exe from project folder (I copied it there before).